# Error message when using drawimage() on a pushed canvas object, not helped by preloading()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

When trying to draw an image on an obstacle in an html canvas game I get this error message: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawimage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.

The obstacle is invisible but the game still stops if the player collides with where it should be. The other stationary obstacles' images in the game are visible. What do I do?

I tried uploading the images in my html as a preload() function but it still doesn't work. Other articles about similar situations do not cover this same context and do not help me who is quite new to programming.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> <link/>

<script> 

function preloader() 

{

 // counter
 var i = 0;

 // create object
 imageObj = new Image();

 // set image list
 images = new Array();
 images[0]="player.jpg"
 images[1]="player2.jpg"
 images[2]="obstacle.jpg"
 images[3]="obstacle2.jpg"
 images[3]="obstacle3.jpg"

 // start preloading
 for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
 {
      imageObj.src=images[i];
 }


 } 

 </script>

</head>
<body onload="startGame(), preloader()">

<h2> My Lost Game </h2>

<p>Press the 'up', 'down', 'left' and 'right' keys on your keyboard to move. Avoid the obstacles and reach the goal.</p><br>

<p></p>

<script>

var myObstacle = [];


function startGame() {
myGameArea.start();
myGameGoal = new component(75, 95, "player2.jpg", 710, 215, "image");
myGamePiece = new component(75, 95, "player.jpg", 10, 215, "image");

myObstacle2 = new component (110, 150, "obstacle2.jpg", 350, 0, "image");
myObstacle3 = new component (110, 150, "obstacle3.jpg", 530, 350, "image");

}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
this.canvas.width = 800;
this.canvas.height = 500;
this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[4]);
this.frameNo = 0;
this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
    myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false; 
})

},
clear : function() {
this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);},

stop : function() {
clearInterval(this.interval);
}
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
this.type = type;
if (type == "image") {
this.image = new Image();
this.image.src = color;
}
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;    

this.update = function() {
ctx = myGameArea.context;
if (type == "image") {
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
        this.x, 
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
} else {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
}
this.newPos = function() {
this.x += this.speedX;
this.y += this.speedY;        
}
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
var myleft = this.x;
var myright = this.x + (this.width);
var mytop = this.y;
var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
var otherleft = otherobj.x;
var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
var othertop = otherobj.y;
var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
var crash = true;
if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
       (mytop > otherbottom) ||
       (myright < otherleft) ||
       (myleft > otherright)) {
   crash = false;
}
return crash;
}
}

function updateGameArea() {
var x, y;
for (i = 0; i < myObstacle.length; i += 1) {
if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle[i])) {
    myGameArea.stop();
    return;
} 
}
myGameArea.clear();
myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
x = 200;
y = 300;
myObstacle.push(new component(110, 150, "obstacle1.jpg", x, y, "image"));
}
for (i = 0; i < myObstacle.length; i += 1) {
myObstacle[i].y += -1;
myObstacle[i].update();
}




myGameArea.clear();
myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -3; }
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 3; }
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -3; }
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 3; }


myObstacle2.update();
myObstacle3.update();
myGameGoal.update();
myGamePiece.newPos();
myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
return false;
}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a  separate image object for each image

The code below loads images from an array of image URLs and returns an array of images in the same order as the URL names

```
var loading = 0; // number of images still loading
function preloader(imageURLs){
    // function creates and loads an image
    function createImage(url){
        loading += 1; // count up when loading images
        const image = new Image;
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = () => loading -= 1;  // count down when loaded
        return image; 
    }
    const images = imageURLs.map(createImage);
    return images;
}    
const imageList = preloader(["player.jpg", "player2.jpg", "obstacle3.jpg"]);
// at this point loading greater than zero
```

When `loading` is 0 you know all images have loaded

Thus in your render loop

```
function mainLoop(){

    if(loading === 0){ // all images have loaded
        ctx.drawImage(imageList[0],0,0);  // draw first image
        ctx.drawImage(imageList[1],0,0);  // draw second image
        ctx.drawImage(imageList[2],0,0);  // draw third image
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Or you can have it call a function when all loaded

```
var loading = 0; // number of images still loading
function preloader(imageURLs, callback){
    // function creates and loads an image
    function createImage(url, callback){
        loading += 1; // count up when loading images
        const image = new Image;
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = () => {
            loading -= 1;  // count down when loaded
            if(loading === 0){ // all done 
               callback();  // call callback
            }
        }
        return image; 
    }
    const images = imageURLs.map(createImage);
    return images;
}    
function start(){  // function to start main loop when images have loaded
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);       
}
// second argument is the callback function that is called when all images have loaded
const imageList = preloader(["player.jpg", "player2.jpg", "obstacle3.jpg"], start);
function mainLoop(){
    ctx.drawImage(imageList[0],0,0);  // draw first image
    ctx.drawImage(imageList[1],0,0);  // draw second image
    ctx.drawImage(imageList[2],0,0);  // draw third image
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```